# How to inform user about multiple important events at one moment

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, notification, popup, modal-windows

I have to show user information about many important events at one moment - e.g. when he enters the app. So far I was showing just one event but now requirements changed and multiple events must be notified. As mobile device real estate is quite limited I cannot afford solution like this:

[image]

Which way to go? Stack those dialogs, make a queue out of them and present to the user in a sequence or what?

Comment: Cant it be part of notification screen where all these information could be stacked up for the user to see?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably group the event messages based on module type and show a badge when collapsed.  You may want to only show modules with events but this depends upon how many modules you have and if your users expect to tap the same module in the same location to expand it.

[image: mobile notifications]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

[image: Notification Suggestion]

Idea is X deletes, lock keeps the notification within the panel, options include swipe to delete etc...

Panel scrolls to show more than 4 notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a mobile web-app or native device app but I think my answer is applicable to either.

My recommendation would be to show a dedicated notification screen either through a non-close-able modal window or a dedicated page.

Upon being presented with this dedicated notification screen they should be given the option to go forward and backward between the notifications and on the final notification just have a button which allows them to close/exit the notifications. Allowing them to swipe left and right would be nice as well.